# Why the number of blocks is always a multiple of 8?

Tags: linux, filesystems

```
$ stat -c %s,%o,%b foo.txt
631,4096,8
$ stat -c %s,%o,%b bar.txt
5952,4096,16
```

Why the number of blocks is always a multiple of 8? I thought the number of blocks of a file is the smallest integer that satisfies `filesize <= blocksize * blockcount`.

Comment: What's the output of `dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep Block` (/dev/hda1 for an IDE disk)?

Comment: Block count:              2441880 /
Block size:               4096 /
Blocks per group:         32768 /
Group 0: ... /

Comment: Since you're using a block size of 4K, the min will always be 8. 4096/512=8. Edit: See Ignacio's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%b` returns the number of blocks on the filesystem that are allocated for the file, where each block is 512 bytes. Since the smallest block on the **filesystem** is 4kB, the number of blocks returned by `stat` will always be a multiple of 8 (4096 ÷ 512 = 8).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still don't understand. 512 bytes? Where does it come from?

Comment: I don't know the entire history, but the sector size of disks used to be 512 bytes.

Comment: 512-bytes blocks dates from the early days of Unix, and stayed in Linux for historical reasons. Thay have no relation to today's hard disks.

Comment: @harry, Ignacio: they are not relating to Unix, but are to harddisks. And while hard disks don't really store information in 512-byte blocks, all of them are using LBA for addressing, which is 512-byte-discrete.

Comment: Everything is a multiple of 8 because computer systems generally describe data in bits (base2 or 0 or 1 per digit) and bytes (base8 or 0-8 per digit) and hex (base 16 or 0-16 per digit) whereas 'normal' math is almost always base 10 (0-10 per digit). BTW, +1 for nice explanation.